# Loading and using devise macros in rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

Following the instructions at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29, I have set up some macros in a file `spec/support/rspec_macros.rb`:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: 4)
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end
  end
end
```

(Note that in my app, "admin" is a role -- role 4 -- that any user can be assigned to, and yes, once I get this working I'll DRY this up and get rid of the magic number).

However, putting `login_admin` into my spec doesn't work: it can't see `login_admin`.

So, following the advice at [ControllerMacros cannot be seen in RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800710/controllermacros-cannot-be-seen-in-rspec) I add

```
config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

to my `spec_helper.rb` file. Now `ControllerMacros` is an uninitialized constant, so following the advice at [rspec not working with devise user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307892/rspec-not-working-with-devise-user-authentication) I add:

```
require 'support/controller_macros'
```

to my `spec_helper` file, and I find that I'm back where I started with `undefined local variable or method login_admin`

Help! How *do* I get to the macro? And is there one single place where the whole process is documented?

For info, the relevant bits of my `spec_helper` file are:

require 'rubygems'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'support/controller_macros'

require 'devise'

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

And my spec file is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

  describe "GET show" do
    login_admin

    it "returns http success" do
      user = User.first
      get :show, id: user[:id]
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `rails_helper.rb` loads files in `spec/support` folder.
If not add that line to your `rails_helper.rb`:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }`
```

after `require 'rspec/rails'` and move devise config to `rails_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```